# SQLiteDiskIOException exception in a Flutter app hat does not use SQL Lite database

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, crashlytics

I have a Flutter app targeting Android. It has been out in the wild for a while, but the other day I got this fatal exception in `Firebase Crashlytics` on `sdmc TV` device on Android 11.

> Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException
> disk I/O error (code 4874 SQLITE_IOERR_SHMSIZE): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode

The weird thing is that I am not using SQL Lite database at all!? I do use `Hive`.

Below is a list of packages I use:

> app_install_date: ^0.1.3
> carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
> encrypt: ^5.0.3
> firebase_analytics: ^10.7.4
> firebase_core: ^2.24.2
> firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.8
> flutter_local_notifications: ^16.2.0
> flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
> flutter_timezone: ^1.0.8
> google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
> hive: ^2.2.3
> hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
> in_app_purchase: ^3.1.11
> in_app_review: ^2.0.8
> intl: ^0.18.1
> json_annotation: ^4.8.1
> json_serializable: ^6.7.1
> just_audio: ^0.9.36
> lottie: ^2.7.0
> numberpicker: ^2.1.2
> path_provider: ^2.1.1
> provider: ^6.1.1
> wakelock_plus: ^1.1.4

What could be the problem here?

Comment: That is definitely an SQLite error code (probably not enough space to create the SHM file (perhaps insufficient access)) see https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_shmsize. If you follow the stack trace you should be able to ascertain what is calling the SQLite API and thus the package (perhaps firebase's device/client). Unless you can remove the offending package you would need to resolve the storage availability issue.

Comment: To clarify see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/Analytics which includes ***Note

The Analytics SDK uses SQLite to persist events and other app-specific data.***